# Get parent child label/value upon checkbox selection of child li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists, frontend

I'm trying to get the value of the lvl1 and lvl2 li labels upon selection of the checkbox of their respective child li.

```
<ul class="list" >
<li class="lvl1">
     <a><h4>Level-1</h4></a>
     <ul>
     <li class="lvl2">
          <a><label>Level-2</label></a>
          <ul>
            <li class="lvl3">
              <input type="checkbox" class="childbox" value="Level-3 Value1"/>
            </li>
         </ul> 
     </li>
     </ul>
<ul>
     <li class="lvl2">
          <a><label>Level-2</label></a>
          <ul>
            <li class="lvl3">
              <input type="checkbox" class="childbox" value="Level-3 Value2"/>
            </li>
         </ul> 
     </li>
     </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I want to get the value upon checkbox for their respective parents-child relationship

Click first checkbox to get this value.

Level-1 > Level-2 > Level-3 Value 1

Click 2nd checkbox to get the below value.

Level-1 > Level-2 > Level-3 Value 2

Comment: I had tried getting the selector using each function.

but i was able to get only for the selection value of the checkbox.

$("input[type='checkbox']").on('click',function(){
                var selected = [];
                $.each($("input[name='secondarycheck']:checked"), function(){
                    //function to do when the radio is selected
                    
                    selected.push($(this).val());
                    //console.log(selected);
                });
                alert("Selection Results: " + selected.join(" > "));
            });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add `on change` event and get all `li` parents of changed input to get the info about the li 'level' I added this as data attribute:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.childbox').change(function(){
      var parents="";
      var current_value=$(this).val();
      $(this).parents('li').each(function( index ) {
          parents= $(this).data('level-name')+" > "+parents;
      });
      console.log(parents+" : "+current_value);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list" >
<li class="lvl1" data-level-name='Level 1'>
     <a><h4>Level-1</h4></a>
     <ul>
     <li class="lvl2" data-level-name='Level 2'>
          <a><label>Level-2</label></a>
          <ul>
            <li class="lvl3" data-level-name='Level 3'>
              <input type="checkbox" class="childbox" value="Level-3 Value1"/>
            </li>
         </ul> 
     </li>
     </ul>
<ul>
     <li class="lvl2" data-level-name='Level 2'>
          <a><label>Level-2</label></a>
          <ul>
            <li class="lvl3" data-level-name='Level 3'>
              <input type="checkbox" class="childbox" value="Level-3 Value2"/>
            </li>
         </ul> 
     </li>
     </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up some example code as to how to do it.  I would use relative selectors to accomplish this.

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
  console.log($(this).closest(".lvl2").find("label").html())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list" >
<li class="lvl1">
     <a><h4>Level-1</h4></a>
     <ul>
     <li class="lvl2">
          <a><label>Level-2</label></a>
          <ul>
            <li class="lvl3">
              <input type="checkbox" class="childbox" value="Level-3 Value1"/>
            </li>
         </ul> 
     </li>
     </ul>
<ul>
     <li class="lvl2">
          <a><label>Level-3</label></a>
          <ul>
            <li class="lvl3">
              <input type="checkbox" class="childbox" value="Level-3 Value2"/>
            </li>
         </ul> 
     </li>
     </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .i was added code for 'leve1,level2' and `label,input` value.you could  select as your wish

```js
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
console.log($(this).closest('.lvl1').text())
console.log($(this).closest('.lvl2').find('label').text())
console.log($(this).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li class="lvl1">
    <a>
      <h4>Level-1</h4>
    </a>
    <ul>
      <li class="lvl2">
        <a><label>Level-2</label></a>
        <ul>
          <li class="lvl3">
            <input type="checkbox" class="childbox" value="Level-3 Value1" />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li class="lvl2">
        <a><label>Level-2</label></a>
        <ul>
          <li class="lvl3">
            <input type="checkbox" class="childbox" value="Level-3 Value2" />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But if i used this(closest) than it will is going to pull the lvl2 elements of next lvl2 list too.